# Cannot add Authenticated Referrals on the developers page

Tags: email, facebook-graph-api, referrals

I'm editing the app, I have access to the Authenticated Referrals box but when I enter email (or another set of user permissions) and choose to save. It doesn't keep the setting. Anyone have an idea on what ma be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a currently open bug report about this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/151208288312040 - there's supposed to be a typeahead / tokeniser in those fields that isn't loading

Answer (score 0):

Did you simply copy/paste the required permissions ? you have to type it directly in the field so it triggers the autocomplete dropdown list.